# React Native, typerError after importing routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm running my react native app in my physical device and when I import routesContainer in my app.js I'm getting that error. Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.635]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.636]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.637]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

that's the error I'm getting after importing routes container, below is my routes.js

routes.js

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    // animationA:AnimationA,
    login: Login,
    welcome: Welcome,
    forgetPassword: ForgetPassword,
    registrationCodeStep: RegistrationCodeStep,
    registrationCode: RegistrationCode,
    coachSignup: CoachSignup,
    playerSignup: PlayerSignup,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);

const CoachStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    dashboard: createStackNavigator(
      {
        coachDashboard: CoachDashboard,
        notifications: Notifications,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    coachTeam: createStackNavigator(
      {
        coachMyTeam: CoachMyTeam,
        createTeam: CreateTeam,
        coachTeamPlayerList: CoachTeamPlayerList,
        playerDetails: PlayerDetails,
        invitePlayer: InvitePlayer,
      },

      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    coachTraining: createStackNavigator(
      {
        training: Training,
        addEditTraining: AddEditTraining,
        coachTeamPlayerList: CoachTeamPlayerList,
        openTraining: OpenTraining,
        locationPicker: LocationPicker,
        playerDetails: PlayerDetails,
        weburl: WebUrl,
      },

      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    coachGames: createStackNavigator(
      {
        games: Games,
        weburl: WebUrl,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    coachChat: createStackNavigator(
      {
        myChat: MyChat,
        chat: Chat,
        addUserChat: AddUserChat,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),

    gallery: Gallery,
    scoreboard: Scoreboard,
    accounts: Accounts,
    changePassword: ChangePassword,
    editProfile: EditProfile,
  },

  {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  },
);

const PlayerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    dashboard: createStackNavigator(
      {
        playerDashboard: PlayerDashboard,
        playerMyTeam: PlayerMyTeam,
        playerDetails: PlayerDetails,
        playerTeamList: PlayerTeamList,
        registrationCode: RegistrationCode,
        notifications: Notifications,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    playerGamesStack: createStackNavigator(
      {
        playerGames: PlayerGames,
        weburl: WebUrl,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    playerTrainingStack: createStackNavigator(
      {
        playerTraining: PlayerTraining,
        openTraining: OpenTraining,
        locationPicker: LocationPicker,
        playerDetails: PlayerDetails,
        weburl: WebUrl,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
    playerGallery: PlayerGallery,
    changePassword: ChangePassword,
    // accounts:Accounts,
    pAccounts: Accounts,
    playerScoreBoard: PlayerScoreboard,
    playerEdit: PlayerEdit,
    playerChat: createStackNavigator(
      {
        myChat: MyChat,
        chat: Chat,
        addUserChat: AddUserChat,
      },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    ),
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  },
);

const RoutesContainer = data => {
  let intial_Route = 'AuthStack';
  if (data.isLogin) {
    intial_Route =
      data.userType == USER_TYPE.PLAYER ? 'PlayerStack' : 'CoachStack';
  }

  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        AuthStack,
        CoachStack,
        PlayerStack,
      },
      {initialRouteName: intial_Route},
    ),
  );
};

export default RoutesContainer;
```

I need to debug that code after 2 days I found out error is in routes.js but don't know what's wrong here? Can anyone tell me

Answer (score 0):

**Focus on Class Names**

At first, If you are sure that you are extending from the correctly named class, e.g. **React.Component**, not **React.component** or **React.createComponent**, if that is case then you may need to upgrade your React version. Below is more information on the classes to extend from.

**Upgrade React**

React has only supported **ES6 syntax** classes since version 0.13.0 (see React official documentation [here](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc#.9nppw7oqv).

But before that, when you are using:

**e.g.)** `class HelloMessage extends React.Component`

You were trying to use ES6 keywords **(extends)** to subclass from a class which was not defined using ES6 class. This was likely why you were running into this unexpected behaviour with super definitions etc.

So, update to React new version.

**Circular Dependencies**

This can also happens if you have circular import structure. One module importing the another and the other way around. In this case you just need to refactor your code to avoid it.[See here](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc#.9nppw7oqv)

Comment: so instead of `const RoutesContainer = data => {` I need to write `class RoutesContainer extends Components { const data = this.props` ?

Comment: Yes, If you are extending from correct class names as mentioned above then it might work!

Comment: can you check my routes.js and tell me, how can i change it?

Comment: Are you importing component from react or not? Go through this docs. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Comment: React from react

Comment: I go through your routes.js file and I am not able to see any classes there. Your code should be in React.Component according to react guidelines!

Comment: Then you have to refactor your code based on those errors

Comment: well I can't it's not my code, my sir give me that code and to refractor I need to understand whats going on in code to understand code need to work, so I'm here